# One of my local bound services depends on another. How can I ensure it's not used until its dependency is ready?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding, initialization-order

I implemented parts of my Android app as two local bound services, one depending on the other. (I only use `bindService()` with them; never `startService()`.) However, when I bind the service which has a dependency, I get a "bound" and "connected" reference to it before its own dependency is ready. This makes calls to some of its methods fail. How can I ensure I don't use my service until its dependent services are connected? Can I delay my service's connection until its own dependencies are connected?

Normally, one only gets references to bound services which are ready to be used, because `onCreate()` and `onBind()` have been called on them already. However, when you call `bindService()` in `onCreate()` of a service `A` for a service `B`, the `onServiceConnected()` callback for the connection to `B` can be (and in my case is!) called *after* the `onServiceConnected()` for the connection to `A`. By default everything's running in the same (main UI) thread, so you can't just make `A`'s `onBind()` wait for the connection to `B` before it returns.

---

I made a simple app to demonstrate the issue. Here are the relevant excerpts. My activity loads the service with the dependency, `ServiceA`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    private final ServiceConnection connectionA = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            serviceA = ((ServiceA.Binder) service).getService();
            setGreeting();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            serviceA = null;
        }
    };

    protected void setGreeting() {
        String greeting = serviceA.getGreeting();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting);
        textView.setText(greeting);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bindService(new Intent(this, ServiceA.class),
            connectionA, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Here's `ServiceB`, which `ServiceA` depends on:

```
public class ServiceB extends Service {
    public class Binder extends android.os.Binder {
        public ServiceB getService() {
            return ServiceB.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new Binder();
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

And here's `ServiceA`:

```
public class ServiceA extends Service {
    public class Binder extends android.os.Binder {
        public ServiceA getService() {
            return ServiceA.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new Binder();
    }

    private ServiceB serviceB;

    private final ServiceConnection connectionB = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            serviceB = ((Service1.Binder) service).getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            serviceB = null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        bindService(new Intent(this, ServiceB.class),
            connectionB, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unbindService(connectionB);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return serviceB.getGreeting() + "!";
    }
}
```

I've added both services to `AndroidManifest.xml`. When I run this, `serviceB` is `null` in the call to `serviceA.getGreeting()` from `setGreeting()`, because `connectionB.onServiceConnected()` has not been called yet.

Is there some way I can make `connectionA.onServiceConnected()` be called only after `connectionB.onServiceConnected()` has been? Or how else can I make sure I don't use `serviceB` before `serviceA.serviceB` has been set?

---

I noticed that if, instead of calling `setGreeting()` directly in `onServiceConnected()`, I `post()` it to the end of the looper's queue, the problem seems to disappear:

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    serviceA = ((ServiceA.Binder) service).getService();
    new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setGreeting();
        }
    });
}
```

I suppose this is because all the `onServiceConnected()` calls to be made happen to be in the looper's queue already, so by waiting for all the current tasks, `serviceA.serviceB` is ready by the time `setGreeting()` gets called. But this feels unreliable to me. Is this reliable? Is there a more reliable way to wait until my services are ready?

Comment: Why do you need two services?

Comment: @Clyde I suppose I don't technically need *any* services; it just seemed like a good way to divide up my code into small units that are created and disposed of as needed, and are injected (via the `Context`). (Could there possibly be a situation where one *needs* to use a local `Service`?) I suppose I could rewrite from scratch a lot of those things to avoid using Android's library. But I was wondering if this is something that can be done with Android's bound services.

Comment: Well, generally speaking you would use a service where you want to do things that need to run asynchronously or in the background, or where you want multiple activities to access a shared resource. The only reason I could think of that you would want to have multiple services is if you were providing services to other apps, which doesn't sound like it's your scenario. So I would suggest you either don't use a service (that depends on what you actually want to do) or if you do, use a single service. If you need the service to do multiple things you can create multiple threads. within it.